# How to set interpreter of WinPython as the vim default python interpreter？

Tags: python, vim

I use a Python distribution named [WinPython](https://code.google.com/p/winpython/). Now I want my vim to use the python interpreter in WinPython as its default interpreter. I tried add the `F:\WinPython\python-2.7.3.amd64` into my windows environment variables `PATH` so that the vim can find `Python27.dll`. Then I use the Vim command `:echo has('python')` and its return 1. However, every time when I use any feature about Python, such as `:python print 1`, the Vim will exit automatically. If I use GVim, there are no warnings and errors showed. If I use Vim Command Line, there is a error 'ImportError: No moulde named site'.

My OS: Win7(64bit)

My Vim version: 7.3(64bit)

My Python: python: 2.7.3.amd64 whit WinPython distribution

Comment: You can't use just any arbitrary Python version; you **must** use the one it was built against.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's OK to use other Python interpreter, because on MS-Windows the Python library can be loaded dynamically. I solved this problem just now, it because I haven't set the environment variables `PYTHONHOME`. Anyhow thank you.

Comment: You can't use python27.dll if it's looking for python26.dll.

Comment: If you use an installed Python, registry entries are set when Python is installed and vim will also check there in order to find where python is installed, because some plugins need access to the `lib` folder. Winpython can be run in "portable" mode in which the registry is not modified, so this is why setting `PYTHONHOME` is necessary, and fixes the problem.  However, this is a poor solution if you run multiple python versions, because each interpreter will check `PYTHONHOME` first and load the wrong files unless `PYTHONHOME` is changed. I don't have a good solution for this scenario yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just now, it because I haven't set the environment variables `PYTHONHOME`. I should set it to the directory of my python interpreter.