# How to set python2 as default python interpreter in vim?

Tags: python, vim, editor, text-editor

I only started using **vim** yesterday and have some questions I can't find a answer to. I want vim to replace my current python editor and since I use only **python2** I need vim to use python2 not python3 syntax checking which is default on my linux machine.

Right now python3 is used:
[image]

I know that vim needs to be compiled with python2 to enable python2 by default but is there any other way?

Comment: Apparently, you would need to recompile (see eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416845/how-to-set-interpreter-of-winpython-as-the-vim-default-python-interpreter - that question was for Windows, though) because vim needs to be linked to the python libs

Comment: I'd see this as a feature. It allows you to write code for python2 that is compatible with python3... You should really start moving towards python3...

Comment: Note that Vim by itself doesn't do syntax checking, only highlighting. You're probably using a plugin like _Syntastic_; this is an important point!